# Azure Blockchain Workbench REST API

Tags: azure, azure-blockchain-workbench, azure-blockchain-service

I am currently trying to access all the information from my Blockchain Workbench.
I use the [REST Workbench API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/workbench/use-api).

The only problem is that I only get 404 errors if I want to get all the available actions for a contract.

Here is my HTTP request:
[image]
And my contracts:

[image]
Does someone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

thanks a lot !!!

Comment: If you do GET api/v1/contracts?workflowId={workflowId}
Do you see the same contract id listed in the response? Where is that screenshot from?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I know I'm wrong - I'm using an app bearer token, not a token from a user - now the question is how to get the token on behalf of a user  :D

Comment: Have you seen this guide? https://medium.com/@malirezaie/how-to-enable-programmatic-interaction-with-azure-blockchain-workbench-apis-56c0d95c79c0